# Excel: Fill rows In table with data from another table Column depending on previous cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-tables

Any help appreciated,
I'm fairly sure this is not possible without VBA as I want to spill information from one table into another.

In Table 1 I have a dropdown list in column 1 that references column 1 from table 2.
when selected i'd like column 2 to fill with column data from table 2 matching the column name to the selection in column 1.

I have simplified the below table for clarity...

Table 1 column 1 data validation: List of =Table2[Col1]

Table 1 (before selection Currently)

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| DropDown | =INDIRECT("Table2["&[@Col1]&"]") |
|  |  |

Table 1 (After selection)

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Col3 | spill |
|  | Spill |
|  | Spill |

Table 2

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Col2 | Item1 | Item4 |
| Col3 | Item2 | Item5 |
| Col3 | Item3 | Item6 |

Table 1 (result I'd like)

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Col3 | Item4 |
|  | Item5 |
|  | Item6 |

I believe I need table 1 to be a table rather than a range as I have information in the rows under this table that will need to shift down depending on the amount of rows used.

If it makes things easier separate table 1's can be had for each entry the first Col.

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: I don't think tables accept spill so if you need it to be a table it can't contain a spill